# Data transformation cropping with Normal Distribution using Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, data-augmentation

I running a model on unsupervised learning for images. Before the images go in for learning I am performing various data augmentations, such as rotate, random erasing, flips, etc. However, I would like to also crop my images based on their Normal/Gaussian Distribution. I am also using the external library called Augmentator which also does not have cropping based on the normal distribution. Its basically just random center or just simply random.

All my transforms go into a list like this:

```
transforms_ = [
transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
# transforms.Resize(int(img_height * 1.12), Image.BICUBIC),
transforms.RandomCrop(img_height, img_width), #this has to be based on normal distribution of the image
transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
transforms.ToTensor(),
# transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
# transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)), # greyscale normalisation 
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I found no external libraries that do this so If i have to implement it on my own I need a way to integrate into Pytorch so any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: copy-n-paste [the original code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/4ec38d496db69833eb0a6f144ebbd6f751cd3912/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py#L390-L479) and change [`random.randint`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/4ec38d496db69833eb0a6f144ebbd6f751cd3912/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py#L452-L453) according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i also think the torchvision augmentator is bad and am thinking about to write my own what operates torch tensors. The reson is, the augmentation must not be pure random, but equally distributed. Means, like  in each epoch all the images are rotated on some small angle, then again, etc, also equaly mirrored, shifted and mirco-noice added. All except rotate are realy easy to implement, and while rotate, you calculate positions ones and apply that to all dataset. 
What i m using now is simple shift method like :

```
def shift_2d_last(self, tensor, distanc_forlast, distance_last):

if distanc_forlast == 0 and distance_last == 0:
    return tensor

moved_tensor = torch.zeros_like(tensor)

last_dim_size = tensor.size(-1)
forlast_dim_size = tensor.size(-2)

begin_to1, end_to1, begin_from1, end_from1 = self.shift_bounds(distance_last, last_dim_size) 

begin_to2, end_to2, begin_from2, end_from2 = self.shift_bounds(distanc_forlast, forlast_dim_size) 


moved_tensor[:,:, begin_to2:end_to2, begin_to1:end_to1] = tensor[: ,: ,begin_from2:end_from2,begin_from1: end_from1 ]


return   moved_tensor
```

Where

```
    def shift_bounds(self, distance, last_size):
    if distance < 0:
        return 0, last_size + distance , -distance, last_size

    return distance, last_size , 0, last_size -distance
```

And mirroring with pytorch flip :
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=flip#torch.flip

And shuffle dataset with :

```
rnd_indexes = torch.randperm(x_train.size(0),device=device )

x_train = x_train[rnd_indexes]
```

Add micronoice just `x_train  + randn(...) * 0.001` or something

Too lasy to implement rotation yet.

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear enough but I don't need rotation. All I need is for me to crop the image based on its normal distribution. I can use numpy to do that but i dont know how it will work with pytorch

Comment: crop is realy easy. tensor x_train  with of shape (batch_size, channels, height, width) is cropped with x_train [:,:,v1:v2,h1:h2]. What actually you mean here based on normal distribution?